# Trac changesets not displaying

Tags: trac

I have set up Trac v0.11.6 to integrate with our VisualSVN server. It all seems to work fine, except when I am viewing source changesets, it only shows the files that have changed, not the actual diff of what has changed in the file.

In addition, when I am viewing a particular file in Trac, the 'diff' link is not visible, which I have seen in other installations.

I assume it is probably a configuration issue, or maybe the way the data is being entered in the first place.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was related to SVN marking certain file types as binary, so Trac didn't know how to diff them. The solution was just to change the SVN mime-type for the problem file types

Answer (score 0):

Large changesets don't show the diffs directly, but should have links to the diffs on a per-file basis.  Unless those files are binary files that can't be diffed meaningfully.  Does that explain what you are seeing?